# how to create custom cscart block

Tags: php, cs-cart

I would like to know how I can send data to any template block that I have created. I need to know who is the controller that is responsible for sending data to the template block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. create your own custom template block into your addon directory ex:my_changes.
   path /design/addons/my_changes/blocks/my_addon.tpl

Code:

```
{** block-description:my_addon **}
{$test_variable|fn_print_r}
```

2. setup your schema for the block.

path:/app/addons/my_changes/schemas/block_manager/blocks.post.php

Code:

```
if ( !defined('AREA') ) { die('Access denied'); }
$schema['my_addon'] = array (
    'content' => array(
        'test_variable' => array(
            'type' => 'function',
            'function' => array('fn_get_my_custom_data')
        ),
    ),
    'templates' => array(
        'addons/my_changes/blocks/my_addon.tpl' => array(),
    ),
    'wrappers' => 'blocks/wrappers',
);


return $schema;
```

3. implement the fn_get_my_custom_data function in your func.php file.

Code:

```
function fn_get_my_custom_data () {return 'hello from my addon';}
```

4. Go to admin panel, design -> layout, then create new block-> create new block Tab, then  you will find your block "_block_my_add_on" there.

This is it. I hope this makes it clear how to associate a controller with a cscart block.

Comment: Its really good detail info. But, after done all the steps also I could not find the block in admin panel.  Can you please help me to resolve this?